# looping zipped list for variables in sql query

Tags: python, mysql, list, nested

I have a table that I want to update, column1 is the primary key

```
| chute | five |
|-------|------|
| Fa01  | null |
|-------|------|
| Fa02  | null |
|-------|------|
| Fa03  | null |
|-------|------|
```

I want to update column 2 with a list of data based upon the key in column 1.

```
sort_list = [('10.0','Fa01'),('23.0','Fa02'),('35.0','Fa03'),('9.0','Fa04')]

query = "UPDATE ship_divert SET five = %s, WHERE chute = %s"
cursor.executemany(query,sort_list)
```

however I get the following error when i run my function that includes this query

```
'...for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE chute = 'Fa01''
```

i have tested the query without variables on my mysql console and it works

```
UPDATE ship_divert   
SET five='28.0'  
WHERE chute = 'Fa02'
```

where is my syntax incorrect in my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `,` in the sql:

```
query = "UPDATE ship_divert SET five = %s, WHERE chute = %s"
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

with this query you can do it in one query. this will be much faster. in the sample i have only 3 Values.

```
INSERT INTO ship_divert (chute,five)
VALUES (
    ('Fa01','10.0'),
    ('Fa02','23.0'),
    ('Fa03','35.0'),
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE five=VALUES(five);
```